# Spring @Transactional commiting partial results even exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cxf

I am running an Apache CXF web service under spring. I use JPA to persist the information. The service has a method that updates a series of rows. Before persisting each row, I check that the values to be persisted really exist in the databes. If there is a value that does not exists, then an Exception is thrown. The problem is I need to rollback al the values updated. I though that using @Transactional in my web service method would do the trick, but instead of that, the values that got persisted are really modified in the database, wich is not the desired behavior.

This is the code of the web service method

```
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )
public UpdateDescriptionResponse updateDescription(UpdateDescriptionRequest updateDescriptionRequest) throws SIASFaultMessage {
    try {
        SubstanceEntity substance = service.findSubstanceBySubstanceID(updateDescriptionRequest.getUpdateDescriptionRequestData().getIdentity().getSubstanceID());
        if (substance!=null){
            for(DescriptionKeyValueType keyValue: updateDescriptionRequest.getUpdateDescriptionRequestData().getSubstanceDescriptionData() ){
                boolean descriptionExists = false;
                for(DescriptionEntity desc: substance.getDescriptionsById()){
                    if (desc.getDescKey().equals(keyValue.getKey())) {
                        descriptionExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!descriptionExists){
                    SIASFaultDetail faultDetail = new SIASFaultDetail();
                    faultDetail.setSIASFaultDescription("Description key does not match given substance ID");
                    faultDetail.setSIASFaultMessage(SIASFaultCode.INVALID_INPUT.toString());
                    faultDetail.setSIASFaultType(SIASFaultCode.INVALID_INPUT);
                    SIASFaultMessage fault = new SIASFaultMessage("Description key does not match given substance ID", faultDetail);
                    throw fault;
                }
                else
                    descriptionLogic.updateDescription(substance.getSubstanceId(), keyValue.getKey(),keyValue.getValue());
            }
            UpdateDescriptionResponse response = new UpdateDescriptionResponse();
            UpdateDescriptionResponse.UpdateDescriptionResponsePackage responsePackage = new UpdateDescriptionResponse.UpdateDescriptionResponsePackage();
            ResponseStatus status = new ResponseStatus();
            status.setMessage(messageOk);
            status.setReturn(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
            responsePackage.setResponseStatus(status);
            response.setUpdateDescriptionResponsePackage(responsePackage);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            SIASFaultDetail faultDetail = new SIASFaultDetail();
            faultDetail.setSIASFaultDescription("Substance ID does not exists");
            faultDetail.setSIASFaultMessage(SIASFaultCode.INVALID_SUBSTANCE_ID.toString());
            faultDetail.setSIASFaultType(SIASFaultCode.INVALID_SUBSTANCE_ID);
            SIASFaultMessage fault = new SIASFaultMessage("Substance ID does not exists", faultDetail);
            throw fault;
        }
    } catch (SIASFaultMessage ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        SIASFaultDetail a = new SIASFaultDetail();
        a.setSIASFaultDescription("Unknown error processing enroll request");
        a.setSIASFaultMessage("SERVICE_ERROR");
        a.setSIASFaultType(SIASFaultCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
        SIASFaultMessage fault = new SIASFaultMessage("Something happened", a);
        throw fault;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the instance of descriptionLogic.updateDescription(...)

```
@Override
public void updateDescription(String substanceID, String key, String value) {
    PageRequest page = new PageRequest(1, 1);
    Map<String, Object> filters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    filters.put("SUBSTANCE_ID", substanceID);
    List<SubstanceEntity> substances = substanceService.findAll(page, filters);
    if (substances.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    SubstanceEntity substanceEntity = substances.get(0);

    for (DescriptionEntity desc : substanceEntity.getDescriptionsById()) {
        if (desc.getDescKey().equals(key)) {
            desc.setDescValue(value);
            descriptionService.persist(desc);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test that fails

```
@Test()
public void testUpdateDescription_does_not_modify_description_with_invalid_values() throws Exception {
    UpdateDescriptionRequest request = new UpdateDescriptionRequest();
    UpdateDescriptionRequest.UpdateDescriptionRequestData data = new UpdateDescriptionRequest.UpdateDescriptionRequestData();
    SIASIdentity identity = new SIASIdentity();
    identity.setSubstanceID("804ab00f-d5e9-40ff-a4d3-11c51c2e7479");
    data.getSubstanceDescriptionData().add(new DescriptionKeyValueType() {{
        setKey("KEY3_1");
        setValue("NEW_VALUE_1");
    }});
    data.getSubstanceDescriptionData().add(new DescriptionKeyValueType() {{
        setKey("KEY3_5");
        setValue("NEW_VALUE_2");
    }});
    data.setIdentity(identity);
    request.setUpdateDescriptionRequestData(data);

    try {
        siasService.updateDescription(request);
    }
    catch (SIASFaultMessage ex){

    }
    DescriptionEntity descriptionEntity1 = descriptionService.findById(1);
    DescriptionEntity descriptionEntity2 = descriptionService.findById(2);
    assertThat("The value does not math",descriptionEntity1.getDescValue(), not(equalTo("NEW_VALUE_1")));
    assertThat("The value does not math",descriptionEntity2.getDescValue(), not(equalTo("NEW_VALUE_2")));
    Assert.assertEquals("The description does not math","KEY3_1", descriptionEntity1.getDescKey());
    Assert.assertEquals("The description does not math","KEY3_2", descriptionEntity2.getDescKey());
}
```

It fails in this line:

```
assertThat("The value does not math",descriptionEntity1.getDescValue(), not(equalTo("NEW_VALUE_1")));
```

This is my datasource configuration in my spring context configuration file

```
.
.
.
<bean id="myDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="myDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="cu.jpa"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="cu.jpa.specifications.IsolationSupportHibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hdm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property value="/META-INF/persistence.xml" name="persistenceXmlLocation"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
.
.
.
```

This is my persistence.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <class>cu.jpa.entities.PatternEntity</class>
    .
    .
    .
    <class>cu.jpa.entities.TraceRegEntity</class>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Extract of the test class:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/repositories.xml"})
public class ServiceImplUpdateDescriptionTest {
    .
    .
    .
    @Test()
    public void testUpdateDescription_does_not_modify_description_with_invalid_values() throws Exception{
    .
    .
    .
    }



}
```

Comment: What type of testcase are you using a transactional one?

Comment: No, the test case is not transactional. The web service call is the one marked as Transactional, inside of it, it throws an Exception, so the transaction should be rolled back. Instead, the transaction is commited anyway, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: Are you extending one of Springs test classes? If so which one. Regarding the transaction you are using CXF make sure that spring is managing the CXF instances (setup integration correctly) else it will not work. IMHO it is also a bad thing to make a web service transactional your service is the transactional layer not the web (be is a UI, SOAP or REST based service).

Comment: Spring is managing correctly the CXF instances.

Comment: I added an extract of the test class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will only rollback the transaction if it is an unchecked exception, if the exception is a checked exception then you will have to add that to your @Transactional annotation.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = SIASFaultMessage.class)
```

Comment: Thanks! that was it. Any ideas why Spring took the decision of not rolling back for every exception?

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it has good explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203860/spring-transaction-rollbackfor-and-norollbackfor-both-defined